# How to read float values from binary file using c#?

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read `float` values from a `binary` file,

```
public static void tmpTest ( )
    {
        string fileName = @"c:\debug\tmp_1.bin";

        /* Write */
        using ( BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter ( File.Open( fileName, FileMode.Create ) ))
        {
            bw.Write ( 10.001f );
            bw.Write ( 10.002f );
        }

        /* Read */
        using ( BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader ( File.Open ( fileName, FileMode.Open ) ) )
        {
            int val_1 = br.Read (); // Output : 25
            int val_2 = br.Read (); // Output : 4
        }
    }
```

I know that I'm missing something at `Read` section, when I read those values I get `val_1` as **`25`** & val_2 as **`4`** instead of 10(as the return type is integer),  please guide me what am I doing wrong here.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use the appropriate Read method when reading the number back out `ReadSingle()` for Float, `ReadDouble()` for Double, etc. [MSDN BinaryReader Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: why am I down voted?? could you please put your comments before you down vote something.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you checked the documentation? There is a [ReadSingle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readsingle(v=vs.110).aspx) method in BinaryReader for that.

```
float value = binaryReader.ReadSingle();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for ReadFloat () & didnt expect this would return float.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read a Single not an Int. If you need an int you can do a cast (int).

[MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readsingle(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
binaryReader.ReadSingle();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using read, instead of ReadSingle. I would assume that the read casting into an int is causing some conversion on your data.

See the following documentation articles about [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ReadSingle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readsingle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)